# How to add custom total of an individual product on order backend page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Basically, on the order edit page, I want to calculate the total of an individual product as price * product_height * quantity_of_products.

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX0EU.png)

I have used the following hook but this hook is not getting executed.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_get_total', 'change_product_total_on_order_edit_page', 10, 2);
function change_product_total_on_order_edit_page ($value, $abc ) {
   var_dump($value);
   die();
   return 15;
}
```

Comment: is it in admin panel ? or front-end details page ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: @Alice If you look to the screenshot, it's on admin orders edit pages, so in backend… But this question is quiet unclear and the hook used in the code doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '`woocommerce_order_item_get_total`' filter instead of `'woocommerce_data_get_total'` because this filter is created dynamically by Woocommerce. The **data** in the hook is object type. When order items are fetched on orders edit page the object type is **order_item**.